# GLES sampler2d will only draw what is in the first texture slot

Tags: java, opengl-es, glsl

Currently using Android Studio, writing in Java and GLES3 a mobile app. I am trying to get multiple textures in my program and it seems that my shader will only draw what is in GL_TEXTURE0, regardless if I set it different or not.
This is the texture class I am using:

```
public class Texture {
    private int[] id;
    byte tex[];
    int slot;

    private void loadImageBytes(Bitmap bm) {
        // ...
    }
    public Texture(Context context, String filename, int textureslot) {
        id = new int[1]; slot = textureslot;
        GLES30.glGenTextures(1, id, 0);
        GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0 + textureslot);
        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id[0]);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        //GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        //GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);

        GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST);

        int height = 0;
        int width = 0;
        try {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(filename));
            height = bm.getHeight();
            width = bm.getWidth();
            tex = new byte[height * width * 4];
            loadImageBytes(bm);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
        }

        GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(tex));
        GLES30.glGenerateMipmap(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    }
    public void activeToShader(ShaderProgram sp, String nume){
        GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
        sp.setUniform1ui(nume, slot);
    }
    /* This is the function that is called here
         void setUniform1ui(String name, int data) {
             int locc = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(id, name);
             if (locc == -1){
                 Log.e("UniformError", "Uniform not found: " + name);
             }
             GLES30.glUniform1ui(locc, data);
         }
    */
}
```

I only use 1 shader program and 1 texture that are initialized once.

```
ts2 = new Texture(getBaseContext(), "apple.png", 1); // I will call this line A
//shader.setUniform1ui("m_texture", ts2.slot);
int locc = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getId(), "m_texture");
if (locc == -1) Log.e("PROGRAM", "Location not found");
GLES30.glUniform1ui(locc, 1);                        // I will call this line B

int locc = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getId(), "thing");
            //GLES30.glUniform1f(locc, 1.0f);

shader.setUniform1ui("thing", 1.0f);
```

There are 2 integer arguments in the lines A and B. In the line A, if I put 0, it will draw the apple regardless of what I put in line B. If I put anything other then 0, it will not draw the apple regardless of what is in line B.
Also, I know it finds the uniform and writes something to it, as I get no errors. Also, I tested the uniform "thing" and it works fine.

Here's the fragment shader:

```
                    "#version 300 es \n" +

                    "precision mediump float;\n" +

                    "out vec4 fragColor;\n" +
                    "uniform sampler2D m_texture;\n" +
                    "uniform float thing;\n" +

                    "in vec2 texUV;\n" +

                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  fragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);\n" +
                    "  fragColor = texture(m_texture, vec2(texUV.x, 1.0 - texUV.y) );\n" +
                    "  if (fragColor.a == 0.0) fragColor = vec4(0, 0, 255, 255);\n" + // modifying the background color into something, works as expected if the texture is in slot 0

                    "  //fragColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, thing, 1.0f);\n" +
                    "}";
```

(when binding the texture to slot 1)The program doesn't show the background, but a black screen most likely from the empty texture 0 slot.
I also tried updating the sampler2d every frame (didn't work), modifying 'thing' every frame (worked fine), using another texture (same results). Also, the max number of textures on my device are 32. I am running a pixel 2 emulator with api 28. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I tried using glGetError and found out that the line that's causing the problem is GLES30.glUniform1ui(locc, 1). I still do not know why nor how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a uniform sampler2D is supposed to take in a int, not an unsigned int, i solved it by using simply `GLES30.glUniform1i(locc, 1);`. I'll leave it here for others with the same problem.